# How can I add text to an xml element with domdocument?

Tags: php, variables, domdocument

I started working with Domdocument in trying to create an XML file.  I found a tutorial that got me to where I can get the file created, but I'm stuck in trying to get one of the elements created.

The first element is created and it looks like

```
<request>
</request>
```

But what I'd like to do is have look like:

```
<request method=".......">
</request>
```

I can't seem to find a way to add the text to the first part without it showing up in the closing part. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not showing us what you have tried.  So it is hard to tell where your code is failing.  Please refer to the [ask] page to help you formulate a better question so you can get better answers and faster.   Welcome to SO

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what to try.  I'm not a programmer at all.  I was about to look through the domdocument documentation.

Comment: I will try to use DOMDocument::createElementNS

Comment: Check this tutorial to see if it helps. http://www.itsalif.info/content/php-5-domdocument-creating-basic-xml   then you can try to create an attribute called `method` using  `public DOMAttr createAttribute ( string $name )` and appending it to the `request` Node

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks Ochi.  Will edit question with the solution...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
     $dom = new DomDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");

     $RequestElem  = $dom->createElement('request');
     $domAttribute = $dom->createAttribute('method');
     $domAttribute->value = 'switchvox.callLogs.search';
     $RequestElem->appendChild($domAttribute);
     $dom->appendChild($RequestElem);

     $ParametersElem = $dom->createElement('parameters');

     $RequestElem->appendChild( $ParametersElem );

     $ParametersElem->appendChild ( $dom->createElement('start_date', '2015-01-19 00:00:00') );
     $ParametersElem->appendChild ( $dom->createElement('end_date', '2015-01-23 00:00:00') );

     $AccountIDElem = $dom->CreateElement('account_ids');
     $ParametersElem->appendChild( $AccountIDElem );

     $AccountIDElem->appendChild ( $dom->createElement('account_id', '1109') );

     $ParametersElem->appendChild ( $dom->createElement('sort_field', 'start_time') );
     $ParametersElem->appendChild ( $dom->createElement('sort_order', 'ASC') );
     $ParametersElem->appendChild ( $dom->createElement('items_per_page', '50') );
     $ParametersElem->appendChild ( $dom->createElement('page_number', '1') );

     $dom->appendChild( $RequestElem );

     $dom->formatOutput = true;

     $dom->save('request.xml');
?>
```